# How to download multiple PDF links automatically using php and store it in my root folder

Tags: php, arrays, dom, foreach, move

I am new to the PHP DOM, I need to know the multiple pdf files downloaded using PHP and stored in my local root folder.

give me the suggestions with the jquery or Ajax method also.

```
     <?php   
$htmlinput = <<<EOT
                    <ul class="property_quicklinks">
                    <li><a href="https://www.uklandandfarms.co.uk/find-a-mortgage/index.aspx?PropertyRef=kObCgeoo">
                        <img src="https://www.uklandandfarms.co.uk/media/icons/ico_home.gif" alt="Find a mortgage for this property">
                        Find a mortgage for this property</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.uklandandfarms.co.uk/search/brochure.aspx?PropertyRef=kObCgeoo" onclick="popUp(this.href,&quot;elastic&quot;,450,550);return false;" rel="external"><img src="/media/icons/ico_document.gif" alt="View a brochure"> View a brochure</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.uklandandfarms.co.uk/search/brochure.aspx?PropertyRef=26208_STR190165" onclick="popUp(this.href,&quot;elastic&quot;,450,650);return false;" rel="external" title="View map (opens in a new window)"><img src="/media/map.gif" alt="View map" class="am"> View map</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.uklandandfarms.co.uk/search/arrangeaviewing.aspx?PropertyRef=kObCgeoo">
                        <img src="https://www.uklandandfarms.co.uk/media/icons/ico_key.gif" alt="Contact agent">
                        Contact agent</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.uklandandfarms.co.uk/customers/saveproperty.aspx?PropertyRef=kObCgeoo&amp;frm=dt"><img src="/media/icons/ico_addnewaccount.gif" alt="Add to my property portfolio"> Add to my property portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.uklandandfarms.co.uk/emailafriend/index.aspx?Ref=UKLF&amp;PropertyRef=kObCgeoo">
                        <img src="https://www.uklandandfarms.co.uk/media/icons/ico_email.gif" alt="E-mail a friend">
                        E-mail a friend</a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.uklandandfarms.co.uk/search/detailsprinter.aspx?PropertyRef=kObCgeoo" onclick="popUp(this.href,'elastic',450,550);return false;" rel="external">
                        <img src="https://www.uklandandfarms.co.uk/media/icons/ico_print.gif" alt="Printer friendly page">
                        Printer friendly page</a></li>
                </ul>
                    EOT;      


                $doc = new \DOMDocument();
                    $doc->loadHTML($htmlinput);
                    $links = [];
                    $arr = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");
                    foreach($arr as $item) {
                      $href =  $item->getAttribute("href");
                      $text = trim(preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", " ", $item->nodeValue));
                      $links[] = [
                        'href' => $href,
                        'text' => $text
                      ];
                    }
            ?>
         <a id="load_URL" target="_blank" class="download_file" href="<?php echo $links[1][href]; ?>" download="<?php echo $links[1][href]; ?>">Download PDF</a>
        <a id="load_URL" target="_blank" class="download_file" href="<?php echo $links[2][href]; ?>" download="<?php echo $links[2][href]; ?>">Download PDF</a>
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for.  Does the code you have work, if not, what is it not doing?

Comment: This code is working.. but I need to download the PDF as automatically